# Error when running go build . with log repo

Tags: go, go-modules

I have a Go program with gomod and when I run `go build .` I got the following error:

> go: github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.4.2 used for two different module paths (github.com/Sirupsen/logrus and github.com/sirupsen/logrus)

my go mod looks like

```
require (

github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2 // indirect
github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2

…

)
```

and I’ve added the following which doesnt help , any idea ?

```
replace (
   github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2 => github.com/sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2
)
```

in my **project code** I use the `import` path with the lower case only `github.com/sirupsen/logrus`

Comment: @Filmzy , this is not duplicate as I did exactly what written in the answer and I add the replace entry which doesnt solve the issue ...any idea how to overcome this?

Comment: @Flimzy , both answer doesnt helps and I already try it...

Comment: I don't see how you could have followed those instructions, and still have the problem, but I can't test it myself right now, so I'll re-open for now.

Comment: @Flimzy - I've added the replace section which should help in this case ,i.e. changing from upper-case to lower case and still it doesnt work when I run go build , I tried also to clean the go-mod cache without success

Comment: The proper import path is `github.com/sirupsen/logrus`. Try `go mod why github.com/Sirupsen/logrus` to find the offending package which still uses a more than two years outdated import path and remove it from your dependency list.

Comment: @Volker - thanks, the command `go mod why github.com/Sirupsen/logrus` return the same error `go: github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.4.2 used for two different module paths (github.com/Sirupsen/logrus and github.com/sirupsen/logrus)` , any other idea/hint ?

Comment: @Volker - this is the output `go: github.com/sirupsen/logrus@v1.4.2 used for two different module paths (github.com/Sirupsen/logrus and github.com/sirupsen/logrus)
`

Comment: @Volker - I use go 1.13

Comment: Then grep your code and all its dependencies for "github.com/Sirupsen/logrus". Or start by removing it from the go.mod.

Comment: Somewhere in your code (direct or probably indirect) you our one of your dependencies uses the wrong import path. Find that wrong import path. Then get rid of that package or have it fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the `//indirect` line, then run

```sh
go mod tidy # prune any extraneous requirements + other stuff
go clean # remove object files and cached files
go get -v -u all # update everything related to the dependencies
go build # finger crossed!
```

Answer (score 0):

`github.com/sirupsen/logrus` is the correct module name as indicated in the go.mod file in v1.4.2 - 
https://search.gocenter.io/github.com~2Fsirupsen~2Flogrus/info?version=v1.4.2

Hence as suggested above, remove the reference of `github.com/Sirupsen/logrus v1.4.2` from your `go.mod` file and run `go mod tidy`. This command will add missing versioned dependencies to your `go.mod` file.